# How to select (highlight) text in a .NET TextBox that is set for ReadOnly?

Tags: .net, vb.net, textbox, selection

My VB.NET programs displays text to the user that is loaded from a text file.  I want to highlight specific parts automatically at various intervals depending on what the application is doing.

I can manually set the highlighted text portion using the `TextBox` control's `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` members.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work if the `TextBox` control has its `ReadOnly` member set to `True`.  What is strange is that my program allows the user to manually click-drag selected text, but text does not get highlighted if the selection is performed programmatically.

The text must be read-only since I do not want the user to modify it.  Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I think a `RichTextBox` would work better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the TextBox SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties, but I'm guessing since the TextBox is ReadOnly, it probably doesn't have the focus.

Try setting this property:

```
TextBox1.HideSelection = False
```

It should work as you expect to now.